# Ubuntu Software says I have Updates pending. But, when I try installing said updates, I get an error saying "snap doesn't have any updates". Help!

Tags: updates, snap

Ubuntu Software says I have Updates pending. But, when I try installing said updates, I get an error saying "snap doesn't have any updates". Help!

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `sudo apt update` and also run `sudo snap refresh`. Read the output of both. If you do not understand the output, then copy/paste the complete output of both into your question above and we will happily explain.

Comment: Thank you! The snap refresh didn't show any output, but the updates vanished from the "Updates" tab on Ubuntu Software. They now appear on the "Installed" tab and both seem to have been updated.